# Returning a list of pairs consisting of the elements of strings and their lengths - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having trouble getting the result to display the information in a list of pairs.

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    """Return the list of pairs consisting of the elements of strings together
    with their sizes.

    add_sizes(list<string>) -> list<(string, integer)>
    """
        c = []
        for i in strings:
            c.append(i)
            c.append(len(i))
        return c
```

The result i get is:

`>>> add_sizes(['sun', 'a'])
['sun', 3, 'a', 1]`

What I'm after is:

`>>> add_sizes(['sun', 'a'])
[('sun', 3), ('a', 1)]`

Answer (score 1):

You need to append tuples instead of appending twice:

```
c.append((i, len(i)))
```

Alternatively, the more pythonic approach is to use a list comprehension:

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    return [(i, len(i)) for i in strings]
```

Comment: Thank you! For the alternative as well

Answer (score 0):

```
def add_sizes(strings):
    """Return the list of pairs consisting of the elements of strings together
    with their sizes.

    add_sizes(list<string>) -> list<(string, integer)>
    """
        c = []
        for i in strings:
            c.append((i,len(i))
        return c
```

But, I think is better to use a dictionary

```
def add_sizes(strings): return {i:len(i) for i in strings}
```